# Trying to add an option to select with append, and nothing happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code has two sections: a section to input new items, and a section to interact with them. I'm trying to update the dropdown list every time a new item is added with jQuery, but my current method does nothing. By nothing, I mean that the dropdown list would remain empty. I've tried previous answers to this question, but none worked. (I'm pretty new to Javascript, so me just being a noob is completely possible).

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link   rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "deletion.css"></link>
    <script src = 'chemical.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id = "newChemicalForm">
        <p id = newChemicalText> Submit new chemicals here: </p>
        <input type = "text" id = "newChemicalInput" onfocus = "this.select()" placeholder = "Enter new chemical here"/>
        <button  id = "newChemicalButton" onclick = "addChemical()" > Submit </button>
    </form>
    <form id = "newUsageForm">
        <p id= "newUsageText"> Name your chemical and a usage amount. Check if the usage is daily. </p>
        <select id = "chemicalDropdown">
        </select>
        <input type = "text" id = "newUsage" placeholder = "Ex: 250"/>
        <input type = "checkbox" id = 'dailyCheckbox'/>
        <p id = "dateText"> Enter the end date below: </p>
        <input type = "date" id = "dateInput"/>
        <button id = "newUsageButton" onclick = "addUsage()"> Submit </button>
    </form>
</body>
```

And the Javascript:

```
chemicals = [];

function addChemical() {
    var chemical = new Chemical();
    chemicals.push(chemical);

    $('#chemicalDropdown').append('<option value = "' + chemical.name + '"> ' + chemical.name + '</option> \n');
}

function Chemical() {
    this.name   = $('#newChemicalInput').val();
    this.amount = 0;
    this.usages = [];
}
```

Comment: What will happen, if you delete the linefeed character -`\n`- at the end of your append statement?

Comment: Any console errors?  I only ask cause your using inline bindings rather than binding in your js.  Oh, and your addChemical() onclick binding is on a 'button' which is in a form.  Are you sure your page is not reloading due to a form submit?  'button' elements in forms act as submits.

Comment: Snippet here with 1.11 works fine. Please note that "does not work" (or in this case "does nothing") is never a good problem description. Of course it does not work. You wouldn't be asking this question if it did. Instead describe the behaviour you witness, and possibly the errors you get. Share your debug information with us.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem without deleting the linefeed. No console errors, but while debugging the code, it was acting very weird when calling addChemical(). By weird, I mean: wouldn't save chemicals in the list if I reset the form, breakpoints wouldn't be paused on, etc. Sorry @Samuruai8, I'll try to be more specific. Once I think of a good description of the problem, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on. First of all, When you press the submit button it tries to submit the first form. Second: It seems like the `onclick` event is not binding to the method which should add the item to the dropdownlist.

I've updated a couple of things:

- Added `$(document).ready(...);` as it is best practice.
- I've removed the inline `onclick` and bind the click event via jQuery.

[JSFiddle here...](https://jsfiddle.net/xbc0k0ne/1/)

```
<form id = "newChemicalForm">
    <p id = newChemicalText> Submit new chemicals here: </p>
    <input type = "text" id = "newChemicalInput" onfocus = "this.select()" placeholder = "Enter new chemical here"/>
    <button type="button" id = "newChemicalButton" > Submit </button>
</form>
<form id = "newUsageForm">
    <p id= "newUsageText"> Name your chemical and a usage amount. Check if the usage is daily. </p>
    <select id = "chemicalDropdown">
    </select>
    <input type = "text" id = "newUsage" placeholder = "Ex: 250"/>
    <input type = "checkbox" id = 'dailyCheckbox'/>
    <p id = "dateText"> Enter the end date below: </p>
    <input type = "date" id = "dateInput"/>
    <button id = "newUsageButton" onclick = "addUsage()"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

and the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var chemicals = [];

  $("#newChemicalButton").on("click",function(){
    addChemical();
  });

  function addChemical() {
      var chemical = new Chemical();
      chemicals.push(chemical);

      $('#chemicalDropdown').append("<option value=" + chemical.name + ">" + chemical.name + "</option>");
  }

  function Chemical() {
      this.name   = $('#newChemicalInput').val();
      this.amount = 0;
      this.usages = [];
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked! Tracking the onclick event (for me) would trigger every time I hit submit, and worked as far as I could tell. To be transparent, I don't really understand why changing to $(document).ready() seemed to fix the issue, since I didn't call any functions until the page was done anyways, but hey, it works! Looks like a good practice to keep. Same with binding in jQuery if possible. If you have any other suggestions (whatever they may be), input is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Possible the "\n" behind the append code make this not working. Try to remove it.